# Gerar números aleatórios em C?

Tags: c, array, random

**Preciso gerar 5 números aleatórios numa faixa entre -10 e +10.** Como eu poderia fazer isto ? Eu já vi que se pode usar `shuffle`, `malloc` ou até mesmo `realloc`, mas por ser novo em C, não entendo muito bem como posso fazer funcionar. Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei grato.

A única parte do meu código, é somente eu ter criado o array com tamanho 5, para poder depois tentar gerar os números aleatórios.

Código :

```
include <stdio.h>
include <stdlib.h>
include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
    int num[5] // este será a variável que irei usar para gerar números aleatórios. 
    return 0;
}
```

Quero também verificar se os números que foram gerados aleatoriamente são positivos ou negativos. Mas ao fazer a verificação, mesmo que dê 5 números positivos, ele coloca negativo como `1`.

Código :

```
int positivo;
int negativo;

if(num[i] > 0) {
    positivo += 1;
}
else if(num[i] < 0 ) {
    negativo += 1;
}

printf("\nPositivo(s) : %d ",positivo);
printf("Negativo(s) : %d ",negativo);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veja a documentação da função [`srand()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/srand.html) (em inglês).

Um exemplo seria assim:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

srand(time(NULL));   // Só deve ser chamada uma única vez
int r = rand();      // Retorna um número inteiro pseudo-aleatório entre 0 and RAND_MAX
```

O valor da macro `RAND_MAX` é [pelo menos 32767](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/rand.html).

Para limitar seu resultado entre `-10` e `10`, use o operador de módulo `%` e um valor subtraindo:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    num[i] = (rand() % 21) + (-10); // Veja [1]
}
```

**[1]** `rand() % N` retorna um número inteiro no intervalo fechado `[0, N-1]`. Com `N=21`, o intervalo será `[0, 20]`. Como você quer dentro do intervalo fechado `[-10, 10]`, basta subtrair `10` do resultado.

**Edit** Exemplo completo online [aqui](https://repl.it/I5he/1), guardando a quantidade de números positivos e negativos.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    int num[5];
    int positivo = 0; // DEVE inicializar
    int negativo = 0; // DEVE inicializar

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        num[i] = (rand() % 21) + (-10);
        if (num[i] > 0) {
            positivo += 1;
        }
        else if (num[i] < 0 ) {
            negativo += 1;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("[%d]: %d\n", i, num[i]);
    }

    printf("Positivo(s) : %d\n", positivo);
    printf("Negativo(s) : %d\n", negativo);

    return 0;
}
```

Você não pode criar uma variável não-estática (variável local) e incrementá-la sem inicializá-la. Variáveis locais são indeterminadas. Na prática, inicialmente elas tendem a ter apenas algum valor sem sentido.

Comment: Não esta funcionando, ele só gera os mesmos números : 0,1,2,3 e 4.

Comment: @Monteiro atualizei a resposta. Execute diversas vezes o exemplo online, se possível. Para mim foram gerados números aleatórios dentro do intervalo pedido.

Comment: @mercador Vlw mano, agora deu certo, não posso dar ainda +1, mas posso dar como resposta correta.