# Gerar números aleatórios em um vetor de floats na linguagem C

Tags: c, array, números-aleatórios

Gostaria de saber métodos de como gerar uma sequência de números aleatórios, que variam de 0 a 10, do tipo float em um vetor do tamanho 10.

Comment: Qual a diferença entre a pergunta atual e [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210172/gerar-n%C3%BAmeros-aleat%C3%B3rios-em-c?rq=1)? Tem algo que esta não atenda?

Comment: @Wtrmute a pergunta que você menciona é sobre números aleatórios inteiros

Comment: @heavydsoul Os números aleatório devem ser gerados por meio da biblioteca padrão ou precisam ser gerados por meio de um algoritmo implementado manualmente ?

Comment: @mercador: E realmente é tão difícil converter um número inteiro num de ponto flutuante? Não entendi.

Comment: @Wtrmute realmente não é difícil, mas a forma é diferente. Talvez o OP saiba fazer com inteiros mas tenha alguma dificuldade com números reais. Fica difícil de saber que problemas ele teve pelo fato da pergunta dele não fornecer tais detalhes.